# Uncompress file from URL to hard disk?

Tags: command-line, bash, unzip

How to uncompress directly from terminal if I have the URL of the file?

For example :

```
unzip www.test.com/test.zip destination-folder-on-my-pc
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `unzip` would have adhered to the [pipes and filters architectural style](http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/pipe_and_filter.html) characteristic of Unix, then one would expect to be able to do this by piping the output of wget into the input of unzip:

```
wget -O - http://www.test.com/test.zip | (cd destination-folder && unzip -)
```

Where the the dash after `-O` means standard output, the dash after `unzip` means standard input and the parenthesised right hand side starts a subshell in the correct directory.

However the ZIP format stores its contents index at the end of the file, and `unzip` needs to read this before it can start decompressing. So, contrary to `gzip` et al, it cannot decompress a stream in one pass.

As a workaround you need a temporary file:

```
wget -O /tmp/z.$$ http://www.test.com/test.zip && 
   (cd destination-folder && unzip /tmp/z.$$)
```

Where the `$$` are just used to generate a non-colliding number.

Instead of running the subshell, you could use the `-d` option of unzip. And for added hygiene, clean up your temporary file:

```
wget -O /tmp/z.$$ http://www.test.com/test.zip && 
   unzip -d destination-folder /tmp/z.$$ &&
   rm /tmp/z.$$
```

Comment: +1 for doing it in one step, and for explaining why the pipe method doesn't work (I tried to do it that way and it failed).

Comment: `unzip` won't take STDIN as you have rightly mentioned..about your second approach have you make it working ? my concern is that both processes around pipe are starting at the same time, so although you are using a subshell `unzip` won't find the file in the right format when it will try to unzip..also pipe seems needless to me in this case, i can't see any work of it..please do correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: Ah, sorry, the pipe should be a `&&`. Fixing that. Thx for pointing this out.

Comment: No problem..also there is no need for a subshell and rather than `cd` to destination you can use `-d` option of `unzip`..  `wget -O /tmp/z.$$ http://www.test.com/test.zip && unzip /tmp/z.$$ -d /where/to/put` ..anyway it seems same to [A.B.'s answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/653523/216503)..

Comment: @heemayl I prefer using double ampersands rather than a sequence of unconditional commands so the command is fail-fast, i.e. stops as soon as one step fails. It's safer and easier to diagnose. If in A.B.'s answer the `wget` fails, there will be the error output of failing `wget`, then failing `unzip` (which shouldn't have run in the first place), then failing `rm`. Of course, this can be remedied by adding a `set -e` at the top of the script.

Comment: You're right over that but i was actually referring to the basic idea :)

Answer (score 7):

You need more than one step:

1. Go into your destination folder

   ```
   cd destination
   ```
2. Download the file

   ```
   wget www.test.com/test.zip
   ```
3. Extract the file

   ```
   unzip test.zip
   ```

---

To use only one command use a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -P "/tmp" "$1"
filename=$(awk -F'/' {print $NF})
unzip "$filename" -d "$2"
rm "/tmp/$filename"
```

- Open an editor to create a new file called `unzip_by_url` and put it either in `~/bin` or `/usr/bin/local`

  ```
  nano unzip_by_url
  ```
- And paste the code above.
- Save and close and
- Make the file executable

  ```
  chmod +x /path/to/file/unzip_by_url
  ```
- Now start the script with:

  ```
  unzip_by_url www.test.com/test.zip destination-folder-on-my-pc
  ```

Comment: No problem..also note that rather than `cd` you can use `-d` option of `unzip` to set a target directory..although in that case you might need the `-P` option of` `wget` to save the zip file there too (depending on OP's  decision)  :)

Comment: @heemayl I was on mobile at this time =)